# Getting "#Error" in SSRS reports - how to diagnose?

Tags: reporting-services, assemblies

I have some custom code that gets called to format certain fields for an SSRS report. Instead of getting the formatted value back as expected, I get the unhelpful message of "#Error". Is there a log or anything that can give me some useful information?

I have verified that the assembly is in the "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies" folder. I copied it over as soon as I built it. I was told not to reference this one from the actual report itself, so I reference the assembly where it was originally built. Someone else in my company does the same thing and her machine is not throwing these errors.

I have also tried both release and debug versions of the assembly, but that does not make a difference. Googling is worthless too, because it keeps matching "#Error" to "Error".

Comment: Can you share some of the custom code?  It might be the cause of your error?

Comment: Hi SidC,

You are correct. The custom code was causing the error. It turns out that custom code was calling another assembly that I did not have in my C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies folder that the other person had put there for another reason.

As soon as I added that assembly to my C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies folder, everything started working correctly. 

Thanks for your input.

Comment: mark as answered then :)

Comment: I would, but I don't see anywhere do to that.